# Add number in circle within text in textview

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

[The number 4 circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHbkK.png)

As you see in the image there is number '4' in a circle within a text and it has a background color. It works as a reference when you click it opens a link in the browser. Is that something can be done in textview using spannable or any other way?

Comment: Isn't this just a unicode character? http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_circled_numbers.html

Comment: No, It is a normal text shown in that way ( `4` )

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Drawable.

Simply create `background.xml` in Drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

And apply background in TextView,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="14dp"
    android:paddingBottom="14dp"
    android:text="04"
```

It will generate the result like this,

[image: Sample]

Comment: I want it to be done within other text. Please check the image again. There is a text on the left and the right number 4 is apart from the text.